# How to show AutoCompleteTextView suggestions in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, landscape, autocompletetextview

AutoCompleteTextView displays it's suggestions in a dropdown in the portrait mode.I would like to display suggestions either in a dialog or in a dropdown in the landscape mode,here the EditText and the keyboard go full screen.

Which layout should I use in the Adapter to display hints as a dialog in landscape mode.
Im currently using `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`.

Comment: I have the same issue..but didn't get any answer

Comment: Im currently forcing the layout to display in `portrait` orientation using `android:screenOrientation`.Considering that there is a Camera that opens only in landscape two Activities back...it is going to be a bumpy ride

Comment: But here that is not my case. I need to get in both modes.

Comment: @shylendra Found an answer,check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I tried it but when I rotate to landscape mode drop down going up how to show it down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the layout where you defined your AutoCompleteTextView use `android:imeOptions=flagNoExtractUi`

The flag prevents the element from going full-screen when it is rotated to landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I tried it but when I rotate to landscape mode drop down going up how to show it down.

Comment: Didn't display the dropdown for me, either.

Answer (score 6):

@vamsiampolu answer is correct but if you want to use same by using java, you can use

```
    itemautoTxt.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

where `itemautoTxt` is `AutoCompleteTextView`

hope this will helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly*, set this `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` in XML.

*Secondly*, your dropdown may be under your keybord or above it. So it may not fit on screen - appear below or above the visible area of the screen. To fix this use `android:dropDownAnchor="@id/your_view"` to pin dropdown to the required view.

*Thirdly*, the dropdown may not appear on some devices or may appear unstable.