# How to add horizontal scrollbar inside AutocompleteTextView in android?

Tags: android, scrollview, autocompletetextview

When text records in AutoCompleteText are more than its height, automatically vertical scrollbar appears, but why when length of text is bigger than AutoCompleteText width scrollbar doesn't appear? How can I add horizontal scrollbar inside AutoCompleteText?

**Main_Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/form_item_style_default"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/refcode_list"
    android:editable="false"
    android:dropDownHeight="170dp"
    android:hint="@string/to_select"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` property for `autocompleteTextView`.

Here is a related post:

[How to show AutoCompleteTextView suggestions in landscape orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906647/how-to-show-autocompletetextview-suggestions-in-landscape-orientation)

PS: I apologize for my English, I used the translator.